how to send text to control with focus on new browser window opened using js.window.open("https://www.bing.com/chat")
how to send text to control with focus on new browser window opened using js.window.open("https://www.bing.com/chat")
I have a web app in python that has a button I can click to open a browser window to bing chat. I can see the new bing chat window with the cursor blinking on the copilot question textbox but how can I send text to the control to ask the question via code

This doesn't seem likely to be possible due to CORS.

In general you have no access to the contents of windows in a different domain.
